# Transaction Isolation level different threads massive number of Writes

Tags: sql-server, transaction, jdbc, isolation-level

I have a lot of threads that writing to DB some data in two tables. **tbl_raw_data** and  **tbl_parsed_data** where **tbl_parsed_data** have foreign key to **tbl_raw_data**.

I also need the writing to be superfast.

While checking the options on improving the writes (asuming reading time is nu so important) a friend of mine told me that I need to check the Transaction Isolation Level that is appropriate for my logic.
after reading some articles regarding this issue what I understand is that this property influence reading.

Is there a Transaction Isolation Level that affect writing? Which isolation level is "best" for lots of Threads running on lots of connections?

Am I looking in the wrong place?

What can I do to improove massive writing?

Im using SQL server, the threads are coming from TomEE server that writes data that came via HTTP requests via JDBC and JPA (ORM).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An ORM requires information about the first write (SCOPE_IDENTITY or such) to complete the second write. This means 2 (with an OUTPUT clause) or 3 database (with SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY) calls in general in a client side transaction.

No amount of tinkering with isolation levels will eliminate these 2 or 3 calls.

If you want more performance, then the best concept stored procedure to do an atomic write (in a transaction) to both tables in one database call. This means 50% or 66% reduction in database calls

Going further, you have to decide what "superfast" really means

For example, should you be using SSDs for your transaction log files: the drive hosting the log files determines overall write speed because of write ahead logging.

Then there the design: are you using IDENTITY columns or GUIDs or Hibernate style nvarchar keys? Has the ORM designed the database for you?

Comment: I designed The DB and used a reversemapping tool to get the objects representation of the data. the IDENTITY columns are autoincrement integers. does IsolationLevel influance the performance in my case?
Do you think the best practice in my case is by using SP?

Comment: Isolation Level will not help you. Yes use a stoerd procedure

Comment: +1 Nice answer, I was thinking of trigger on Insert, will that help in this case? that will not work incase data are different in both the table.

Comment: How would the trigger on first table know what data is to go into the second table? A stored procedure does the same with more visibility

Comment: right, stored procedure is the best option here.

Comment: Writes to a SQL Server 2014 in-memory OLTP table are "superfast".  Enterprise-only though.

Answer (score 2):

The only isolation level that influences *writes* is SNAPSHOT (and the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT). Snapshot isolation requires row versioning and row versioning requires extra writes. Read [Understanding Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050(v=sql.105).aspx).

Now about the 'super-fast' part of the question: the 'super-fast' option for INSERT is the bulk insert path. This requires a client API that understands bulk-insert: [`IRowsetFastLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131708.aspx) in OleDB, [ODBC `send_row`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130792.aspx) or managed .Net [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx), [`EnableBulkLoad=true` for JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13753/mssqlserver.htm). You do not want 'lots of threads running lots of connections', you want **one** thread doing lots of inserts, in bulk API mode. Use a producer-consumer pattern in the app to funnel all your app threads to one single bulk writing thread.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk writes indeed are fast but will not be logged. If that is not what you want, consider procedure calls with table valued parameters. That way we have realised significant write improvements.

Comment: Bulk insert *can* be [minimally logged](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244(v=sql.105).aspx), *if* possible. There is no such thing as 'not logged write'.